# How to construct orthogonal tangents to an ellipse

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Given an ellipse, we want to draw a set of tangents to it, which are orthogonal to each other.
We are looking for a synthetic way; not through algebra or trigonometry.

I know how to construct one tangent:
Given any point $P$ on the ellipse, we connect it with the two foci, say $F_1$ and $F_2$ and then we bisect angle $F_1PF_2$. The bisector is the "normal". Then we draw an orthogonal line to the bisector, from point $P$f and this is our tangent.

I am trying to think of a way to construct another tangent, orthogonal to it.
Clearly the normal of the second tangent will be orthogonal to the 1st normal.
We are looking for the single point $Q$ (or maybe 2 points), for which, the 2nd normal will bisect angle $F_1QF_2$ but I can't think of any way to construct it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but "which are vertical to each other" doesn't mean anything... Please correct it. Maybe you wanted to say "orthogonal" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry but English is not my mother tongue. I corrected it.

Comment: I have changed in your question all remaining adjectives "parallel" into "orthogonal" which is the most appropriate term for 2 lines making a 90° angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to construct a second tangent, perpendicular to the first one you constructed at $P$. Let the normal at $P$ intersect again the ellipse at $N$ and let $M$ be the midpoint of $PN$. The line passing through $M$ and the center $O$ of the ellipse will then intersect the ellipse at two points $Q$ and $Q'$, [with the property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Conjugate_diameters) that the tangents at both points are parallel to $PN$, and hence perpendicular to the first tangent.

As I wrote in a comment, the intersections between the tangents at $Q$ and $Q'$ and the tangent at $P$ lie on the [director circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle) of the ellipse.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant solution! Is there a proof?

Comment: If the Wikipedia proof I linked is not enough, I could try to provide another proof.

Answer (score 1):

This being my first contribution to the forum, let me hope that I got the formatting and importing procedures correct.

I have constructed a tangent through point *P* just as you said, bisecting ∠*F*₁*PF*₂, and constructing the tangent perpendicular to that bisector.

Through center *O* I have constructed a diameter perpendicular to the tangent line at *P*. It meets the ellipse at *Q*, and there I have constructed another tangent line using the same angle bisection method.

Through *O* I have constructed a second diameter, parallel to the tangent at *Q*. This diameter meets the ellipse at points *A* and *B*.

Lines *OQ* and *AOB*, are conjugate diameters. I have constructed lines through *A* and *B*, both parallel to *OQ*, which makes them tangent to the ellipse. It also makes them perpendicular to the tangent through *P*.

[ellipse construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65lRz.png)